# Python : how can I get the value of an Entry in a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner in python and I'm creating an interface where I can click on a button to open a new window and then fill a form.

My problem here is about to get the value of the entry after the customer pressed the button print.
First as you can see I created a window.
This is example of what i want to do.

```py
def return_nom(*args):
    return ent1.get()


def save():
    print("your name is", return_nom())


def new_win():
    top = Toplevel(fen)
    top.title("new window")
    strvar = StringVar()
    strvar.trace("w", return_nom)
    ent1 = Entry(top, textvariable=strvar)
    bouton1 = Button(top, text='print', command=save)
    bouton1.pack()
    ent1.pack()
    top.mainloop()


fen = Tk()
lab = Label(fen)
lab.pack()
bouton = Button(fen, text='new window', command=new_win)
bouton.pack()
fen.mainloop()
```

If someone can tell me why it doesn't work and explain me why this technique works when I use this it for an entry on the main interface.
Thanks everybody ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you have here is *scope*, since you're trying to access the Entry and StringVar from functions that don't have access to it.

The name `ent1` defined inside `new_win()` will not be accessible from `return_nom()`.

Furthermore, it seems to me that what you actually want to query is the StringVar and not the Entry widget itself.

How you can pass the StringVar to the called functions, there are several ways:

- Make the `strvar` a global variable, that way the other functions will have access to it. This is probably the worst possible solution to this problem, since the point of having functions is to avoid namespace pollution of a global namespace.
- Make the `return_nom()` and `save()` functions inner functions of `new_win()`, which allows them to access the local variables in `new_win()` as a closure. This is slightly better.
- Use an object-oriented interface, where your StringVar is an instance member and your `save()` is a method. State such as the StringVar is available to the whole instance. This is probably the best here, it's how Tkinter is actually intended to be used, it most naturally fits an object-oriented approach.

An example of using inner functions would be:

```
def new_win():
    top = Toplevel(fen)
    top.title("new window")
    strvar = StringVar()
    def return_nom(*args):
        return strvar.get()
    def save():
        print("your name is", return_nom())
    ent1 = Entry(top, textvariable=strvar)
    bouton1 = Button(top, text='print', command=save)
    bouton1.pack()
    ent1.pack()
    top.mainloop()
```

An example of an object-oriented approach would be:

```
class MyDialog:
    def __init__(self, fen):
        self.fen = fen
        self.strvar = StringVar()

    def return_nom(self, *args):
        return self.strvar.get()

    def save():
        print("your name is", self.return_nom())

    def new_win(self):
        top = Toplevel(self.fen)
        top.title("new window")
        ent1 = Entry(top, textvariable=self.strvar)
        bouton1 = Button(top, text='print', command=self.save)
        bouton1.pack()
        ent1.pack()
        top.mainloop()
```

And then at the top-level:

```
my_dialog = MyDialog(fen)
bouton = Button(fen, text='new window', command=my_dialog.new_win)
```

But the above is still not the best approach, which would actually be to create subclasses of `Tkinter.Frame` for your windows, connect them together through methods and have your top-level code only instantiate a main Application class and call `app.mainloop()` on it, letting it drive the whole application flow through events connected to methods and other frames.

See [a simple Hello World program](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program) in the Python tkinter documentation on the Python standard library to get a somewhat better idea of how tkinter is intended to be used.

That documentation also has pointers to many other resources on tkinter and on Tk itself that you can follow to get more in-depth knowledge of that toolkit library.

Comment: This is perhaps a good example of how to launch a dialog window from a main window: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Comment: Thank you for your help and the documentation ! 
I need to understand functions scope better too.
Awesome!!! I get it better now.

Answer (score 0):

Check what the traceback is telling you when you start typing:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "tktest.py", line 3, in return_nom
    return ent1.get()
NameError: name 'ent1' is not defined
```

When you define a variable in a function, it's not automatically defined in other functions. That's called "scope of a variable". Either you define `ent1` in the new_win() function with the `global` keyword or you make it a function attribute:

```
new_win.ent1 = Entry(top, textvariable=strvar)
...
new_win.ent1.pack()
```

and call it like that:

```
def return_nom(*args):
    return new_win.ent1.get()
```

Happy programming!

Comment: Either that or you make it a function attribute. I added more details in my answer.

Comment: Ok ok I didn't know I could make en variable en function attribute as 'new_win.ent1'. Do you know a website or books where I can learn more about bases and advanced things ? 
Thank you so much for your help !